# background image expanding with the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem in a scenario where I need my background image to expand dynamically with the content in the body.

```js
function myclick() {
  var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.'


  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text + text;

}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background {
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-87.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 4.2%;
  height: 100%;
}

.base {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: auto;
  width: 665px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="base">
        <p id="demo"></p>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas
        expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram. Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto
        mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an. Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur
        id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his. Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu.
        His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei. Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas
        consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="myclick()">Click me</button>

</body>
```

if you click on the button on the top the content of the body increases but the size of the background still remains same.
Is there any way to have this working?

Comment: Remove the html and #body css definitions, body is all you need.  Make sure you include a dtd as the first line of your html or css height won't work either.  Move the background css content into body.

Comment: If I remove the body and html css the background height will be only till the content ends. But I need The bg image to be fit to the screen when there is less content and the bg image to dynamically expand if the content increases.

Comment: I can see you set "background-color: white;" for base. This is preventing to see the outer background. Also set "overflow: auto;" on ".background" class.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `min-height:100%;` instead of `height:100%;` in `.background` class

```js
function myclick() {
      var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.'


      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text + text;

    }
```

```css
html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #root {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .background {
      background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-87.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-bottom: 4.2%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .base {
      margin: auto;
      background-color: white;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
      height: auto;
      width: 665px;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      top: 40px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="root">
        <div class="background">
          <div class="base">
            <p id="demo"></p>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas
            expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram. Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto
            mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an. Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur
            id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his. Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu.
            His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei. Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas
            consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onclick="myclick()">Click me</button>

    </body>
```

Comment: That is body default colour you can add `body { margin:0px;}`

Answer (score 0):

There's a css property Background-Size

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

`background-size: cover` may be a good fit for your use case. Another option is `contain`.

Comment: And it is covering the background element. The problem is that `height:100%` is set on .background. maybe try min-height: 100%

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height of your background class and add a float left to it (also give it width 100% to manage the float)

Here's a working example:

```js
function myclick() {
  var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram.Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus volutpat. Cum elit libris an.Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his.Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei.Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.'


  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text + text;

}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background {
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-87.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 4.2%;
  /* height: 100% */
  width: 100%;
  /* To manage float resize */
  float: left;
  /* To follow content height */
}

.base {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: auto;
  width: 665px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="base">
      <p id="demo"></p>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat minim per eu. Eligendi maluisset ea pri, at per brute reque dissentias. In nisl latine voluptua pri, his et omnesque contentiones, te ius possit consequat. Vel error aeque ad, sit putent graeco adipiscing no. No sit fabellas
      expetenda, ea usu ignota antiopam qualisque, vix at tantas dictas electram. Sea ne wisi aeterno, qui ei zril graece dolorem. Ut nec vero assueverit voluptatibus, tantas dictas ei sit, hinc aperiri vix et. Quod molestie pri ad. Has te detracto mandamus
      volutpat. Cum elit libris an. Sumo epicurei est te, ad nec cibo facilisi theophrastus. Vim eu delenit sensibus ocurreret, id repudiandae mediocritatem est, ei verterem voluptatibus eam. Eu omnes insolens qui. Quodsi tibique efficiantur id nam, et
      vel oratio diceret. Id sed admodum sapientem. Debitis assueverit sit at, no audire torquatos nam, an graece iuvaret his. Putent persius abhorreant pro ad, dicam vocent habemus et eos, ne wisi mazim bonorum quo. Atqui vulputate an usu. His ut quot
      quidam quaestio, vim ei voluptatum interesset. Ei mei amet phaedrum adipisci, no mundi saperet petentium sed. Vim mazim timeam ei, cu adhuc persius graecis sit, suas sint alienum in mei. Duo et summo nobis cotidieque, reque tantas consetetur id
      usu. Eum doctus labitur cu. Est at diam tollit inermis, pro at elitr petentium dissentiunt. Cu fugit singulis persequeris nam, eum cetero ornatus similique no. Case mollis ius ex, aperiri honestatis persequeris ad vix.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myclick()">Click me</button>
```